# Toggle "addClass" at 3 divs successively

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my html:

```
<div class="button"></div>
<div class="wrapper>
  <div class="something">Hello</div>
  <div class="box one">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box two">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box three">Box 3</div>
</div>
```

By clicking the div "button", I want to add the class "active" to the first div with class name "box". If I clicking the button again, I want to remove the class "active" from box 1 and add it to box 2. Aso.

Later, if box 3 has the added class name "active" and I press the div "button" again, it should start from the beginning.

I try something like this, but it fails:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    $(this).find(".wrapper").add(".box").toggleClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Is the HTML correct? `.wrapper` is not a child of `.button`.

Comment: @acdcjunior Yes, the HTML is correct - but the js was wrong, sry - I have updated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use css `:eq()` selector or `.eq()` on jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var index = 0; // define index for the first box
  $('.button').on('click',function(){
    $('.wrapper .box').removeClass('active');   // remove class active from all box divs
    $('.wrapper .box:eq('+index+')').addClass('active');  // add class active to the box index we need
    index = (index < $('.wrapper .box').length - 1) ? index +1 : 0;  // if index = the number of box divs add + 1 if not return it back to 0
  }).click(); // if you need to run it onload add .click()
});
```

```css
.active{
  background : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">Click</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="something">Hello</div>
  <div class="box one">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box two">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box three">Box 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Pepe You're welcome .. please read the comments in the code .. Have a great day :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```js
jQuery(".button").click(function(){
   var active =  jQuery(".wrapper").children(".active").first();

   if (!active.length)
    jQuery(".wrapper").children(":first").addClass("active");
   else{ 
     active.removeClass("active");  
     if (active[0] != jQuery(".wrapper").children(":last")[0])
       active.next().addClass("active");
     else
       jQuery(".wrapper").children(":first").addClass("active");
   }
});
```

```css
.button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.5px;
  border-radius: 9px;
  position: relative;
  left: 30%;
}

.wrapper {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 450px;
  height: 550;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: dashed;
}
.active {
  background-color: grey;
}
.something {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.box {
  margin-bottom: 8px;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">
<p>Press Me</p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="something">Hello</div>
  <div class="box one">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box two">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box three">Box 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some fun with generator functions :)

```js
let box = 0;

$('.button').on('click', function() {
 const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box'); // get all boxes
 let iter = activateBox(box, boxes); // create itarator to go over boxes
 
 $('.box').removeClass('active'); // remove any active class from all boxes
 
 iter.next(box++).value.classList.add('active'); // add active class to the next box in line
 if (box === boxes.length) box = 0; // reset counter if last box reached
});

function* activateBox(i, boxes) {
 yield boxes[i];
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px solid lightblue;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background .15s ease-out;
}

.button:hover {
  background: lightblue;
  color: #FFF;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: 2px solid lightblue;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.box.active {
  background: lightblue;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">Apply Active</div>
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="box one">Box 1</div>
 <div class="box two">Box 2</div>
 <div class="box three">Box 3</div>
</div>
```